# can you override an override in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Just curious, can you override an override in actionscript 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
class Foo {
    public function bar():void { }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo {
    override public function bar():void { }
}

class Foo3 extends Foo2 {
    override public function bar():void { }
}
```

Note that `super.bar` in `Foo3` will necessarily refer to `Foo2.bar`. Therefore if you expect to be doing this it's sometimes handy to create a `protected` function in `Foo2` that just calls `super.bar` so that you can access the base implementation when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can... here is some pseudo-code

```
public class Test1 
{
   public function doSomething():void
   {
      trace( 'Test1' );
   }
}

public class Test2 extends Test1
{
   override public function doSomething():void
   {
      super.doSomething();
      trace( 'Test2' );
   }
}

public class Test3 extends Test2
{
   override public function doSomething():void
   {
      super.doSomething();
      trace( 'Test3' );
   }
}
```